# How to merge two different jscoverage.json files?

Tags: json, code-coverage, jscoverage

I am taking coverage using jscoverage . Now the problem is after storing the report for say 15 times it stops working .So i get a report with some lines covered . Now if i again try to start the coverage freshly and try to merge the jscoverage.json of the new and the old files then it gets corrupted . Can someone suggest how to merge two jscoverage.json files ??

NOte: the coverage i am taking is for the same js file so directory and everything remains the same .

Answer (score 0):

You can merge reports using JSCover (successor of jscoverage). Use the following command,

```
java -cp JSCover-all.jar jscover.report.Main --merge REPORT-DIR1 REPORT-DIR2 REPORT-DIR3...DEST-DIR
```

See,

http://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/manual/manual.xml#reportMerging

Comment: JSCover's JSON format changed to accommodate branch coverage (http://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/manual/manual.xml#jsCoverageVJSCoverJSON) - so can no longer be used to merge jscoverage's JSON (though an older version of JSCover might work, or be easily modified to work if you want to go to that trouble).